# Is the "though" unnecessary in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> She slammed the door behind her.
>   *Nice girl*. With her gone, **though**, the air felt a few pounds lighter.

Many people had said that the *though* is unnecessary. However, this is how I read it: The girl slammed the door (a rough action). She was a nice girl (sarcasm), **but** I had to admit that the tension dissipated once she was gone.

So the **though** corresponds to the **but**. Or maybe I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

*Though* seems odd to me in this context. If **nice girl** is sarcasm, the writer was glad to see her go. The "lightening of the air" is congruent with that thought, so it does not call for a *contrastive* word such as *though*.

I think it would make more sense rendered thus:

- **And** with her gone, the air felt a few pounds lighter.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about style and semantics, not about grammar.

Grammar-wise, there is nothing wrong here.

But:

*Though* implies a contradiction, a deviation from the expectation or the norm. *Logically* you would expect the tension to go away when an unpleasant person leaves. If you add the *though*, you express a contradicting expectation: A *surprise* that "the air felt a few pound lighter".

As we don't know what you want so say - the above *could be your intention*, after all - it's hard to say "it's wrong". If you simply wanted to express "girl gone -> tension gone as expected", dump the *though*.